# Python: Use file ctime and mtime differential backup

Tags: python

I want to use the file ctime and mtime differential backup. However，the set values of the dictionary do not support multiple

```
fileInfo = {'/root/py/backup_tar/backup.log': [1382945505.0, 1382945505.0], '/root/py/backup_tar/fileinfo.pk': [1382943020.0, 1382943020.0], '/root/py/backup_tar/test.tar.gz': [1382945505.0, 1382945505.0], '/root/py/backup_tar/file_backup.py': [1382944678.0, 1382944678.0], '/root/py/backup_tar/tar.py': [1382693438.0, 1382693438.0], '/root/py/backup_tar/test.pk': [1382945505.0, 1382945505.0]}

old_fileInfo = {'/root/py/backup_tar/tar.py': [1382693438.0, 1382693438.0], '/root/py/backup_tar/file_backup.py': [1382944678.0, 1382944678.0], '/root/py/backup_tar/test.pk': [1382945487.0, 1382945487.0], '/root/py/backup_tar/fileinfo.pk': [1382943020.0, 1382943020.0], '/root/py/backup_tar/backup.log': [1382945377.0, 1382945377.0]}

difference = dict(set(fileInfo.items())^set(old_fileInfo.items()))
fileNum = len(difference)
print fileNum

difference_file = ' '.join(difference.keys())
print difference_file
```

Does anyone know how I could solve this?

Comment: Your question is rather unclear, what is it that you want?

Comment: Please explain the question clearly, if possible please provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: presumably a list of files that need to be backed up; anything that is in `fileInfo` but not in `old_fileInfo`, and anything in `fileInfo` that has *changed* since `old_fileInfo`. `set`s are certainly not the way to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you want, as you refrain to tell us what exactly goes wrong (do you get a stacktrace? Then please tell us...), but from your question I could imagine that you just have to replace the lists with tuples. So, `(1382693438.0, 1382693438.0)` instead of `[1382693438.0, 1382693438.0]`.

Comment: This would not tell the OP what files to back up, however. There is a lot of barking up the wrong tree going on here.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to loop over `fileInfo` manually, sets are the wrong tool here. You *can* find 'missing' items with [dictionary views](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), which do use set operations:

```
# all items in fileInfo that are not in old_fileInfo
to_backup = fileInfo.viewkeys() - old_fileInfo

# find changed, all items in fileInfo that *are* in old_fileInfo
for f in fileInfo.viewkeys() & old_fileInfo:
    ctime, mtime = fileInfo[f]
    old_ctime, old_mtime = old_fileInfo[f]
    if ctime != old_ctime or mtime != old_mtime:
        to_backup.add(f)
```

This produces a set of filenames to back up.

In Python 3, use `fileInfo.keys()` instead of `fileInfo.dictkeys()`. In Python 2.6 and older, use `set(fileInfo)` instead of `fileInfo.dictkeys()`.

Demo:

```
>>> fileInfo = {'/root/py/backup_tar/backup.log': [1382945505.0, 1382945505.0], '/root/py/backup_tar/fileinfo.pk': [1382943020.0, 1382943020.0], '/root/py/backup_tar/test.tar.gz': [1382945505.0, 1382945505.0], '/root/py/backup_tar/file_backup.py': [1382944678.0, 1382944678.0], '/root/py/backup_tar/tar.py': [1382693438.0, 1382693438.0], '/root/py/backup_tar/test.pk': [1382945505.0, 1382945505.0]}
>>> old_fileInfo = {'/root/py/backup_tar/tar.py': [1382693438.0, 1382693438.0], '/root/py/backup_tar/file_backup.py': [1382944678.0, 1382944678.0], '/root/py/backup_tar/test.pk': [1382945487.0, 1382945487.0], '/root/py/backup_tar/fileinfo.pk': [1382943020.0, 1382943020.0], '/root/py/backup_tar/backup.log': [1382945377.0, 1382945377.0]}
>>> to_backup = fileInfo.viewkeys() - old_fileInfo
>>> for f in fileInfo.viewkeys() & old_fileInfo:
...     ctime, mtime = fileInfo[f]
...     old_ctime, old_mtime = old_fileInfo[f]
...     if ctime != old_ctime or mtime != old_mtime:
...         to_backup.add(f)
... 
>>> to_backup
set(['/root/py/backup_tar/backup.log', '/root/py/backup_tar/test.tar.gz', '/root/py/backup_tar/test.pk'])
```

Comment: 'dict' object has no attribute 'viewkeys', This method is complex. Sorry, I didn't say it clearly. This question use to replace the lists with tuples.

Comment: @yeho: Then you either are using a python version older than 2.7, or use Python 3.x. `set(fileInfo)` gives you the same object on older Python versions, albeit in a less efficient manner. For Python 3, use `.keys()` instead, as those are dict view methods now.